# How to tell google bot to skip part of HTML?

Tags: html, css, seo

There is much info about opposite situation, when people try to have stuff in HTML, that is visible to Google bots, but not visible to users, in my case, I need opposite thing - to hide some of the html from google bot. The question would be how?

Flash is not an answer,
Would prefer not to use fancy ajax things also (mainly because I need it right away, not on document ready),
Also robots.txt is not an answer, because it works on urls, not parts of the page.
Would any special css/simple javascript work, is any special html tag for this?

Comment: _why_ do you want to hide information from Googlebot? What is the _purpose_ of doing so? There may be other ways to achieve the goal than hiding HTML.

Comment: Uhmz.. I'm pretty sure googlebot doesn't know how to read images...

Comment: mmm what about using an iframe? you can create a separated html, exclude it en robots.txt, and in your page call de html on a iframe

Comment: to be honest, I don't know why my client wishes this, he has some SEO consultant and I think that was his idea. If it really matters why, I could ask (problem is 8 hours time difference between me and client), but till that time would be nice to know alternatives.

Comment: Images is not an option, as content is dynamic (actually is part of navigation). Iframes - I had that idea, but I hate them, so let's leave that as an escape option.

Comment: @Giedrius - beware the SEO consultant that wants to show one set of content to Googlebot and another to users. This is cloaking, plain and simple. I understand that you want to prepare alternatives, but don't implement them until you know the reason - it could be very bad for your client.

Comment: I'm using pseudoclass :after on my CSS to add some text (This don't work with html, of course). example css: h1:after { display: block;  content: attr( data-note ); margin: 0 0 20px 0; color: #af0000; font-weight: bold; } Example html: <h1 data-note='This example works only on centos Linux'>Tutorial about something</h1>. I think this can't be indexed by google, well only if google becomes more crazy than it is :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe a base64 encoding server side and then decoding on the client side could work?

Code:

```
<!-- visible to Google -->
<p> Hi, Google Bot! </p>

<!-- not visible from here on -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write ("<?php echo base64_encode('<b>hey there, user</b>'); ?>");
</script>
```

How it looks to the bot:

```
<!-- visible to Google -->
<p> Hi, Google Bot! </p>

<!-- not visible from here on -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write (base64_decode("B9A985350099BC8913=="));
</script>
```

Comment: Good idea. For large amounts of HTML you can use AJAX  (if you have jQuery or almost any other library, it's really easy... if you have no library, still easy to implement and may be a better solution than base64 as you dont have to encode your html each time you change it)

Comment: This solution does not work, because the [Googlebot is able to parse and execute JavaScript](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) nowadays.

Comment: @modiX it wasn't the best solution even back then, it's kinda hacky. But OP's client wanted it this way. Still, if Google is executing JS and indexing the results, CSS can be used via `display: none` AFAIK Google respects hidden elements and doesn't index the contents.

Answer (score 5):

Create a Div, 
Load the content of the Div (ajax) from an html file which resides in a directory protected by robots.
Example.
/index.html

Somewhere on the header. (check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ )

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/hiddendirfrombots/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#hiddenfrombots').html(data);
  }
});
```

... 
somewhere in the body

```
<div id="hiddenfrombots"></div>
```

create a directory "hiddenfrombots" and put the followin in the roots .htaccess

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /hiddenfrombots/
```

Comment: Now as the Google bot understand javascript&ajax ... does it check robots.txt also for urls called via ajax?

Comment: Yes it does! If you put your the url-s to be called via Ajax in a specific folder, you can just tell Google-robots to ignore that folder.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the Trick:

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
<p>hide me!</p>
<!--googleon: index-->
```

For more information check out the link to Googles page that describes it in more depth.

[Excluding Unwanted Text from the Index](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076243)

Comment: Only for Google search appliances

Answer (score 2):

If you can use PHP, just output your content if not Googlebot:

```
// if not google
if(!strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot")) { 
    echo $div;
}
```

That's how I could solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Load your content via an Ajax call
- But create a JS file (e.g.: noGoogleBot.js) that contains the function that implements the ajax call:

  ```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'anything.html',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#anywhere').html(data);
    }
  });
  ```

Then in your robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /noGoogleBot.js
```

So all the divs that are loaded using the function in noGoogleBot will be blocked.
Googlebot (or any other crawler) will ignore the content of noGoogleBot.js.

Answer (score 0):

Per Google [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag?hl=en#data-nosnippet-attr)

```
<p>This text can be shown in a snippet
<span data-nosnippet>and this part would not be shown</span>.</p>
```

Adding `data-nosnippet` to `div`, `span`, or `section` prevents the content from being shown in the search result.

Answer (score -1):

simple, create an image with the text you don't want Google to see

Comment: Downvote, Google does have sophisticated OCR for image capabilities.

Comment: afaik only for PDF documents, or do you have a reference?