# How to "manipulate" google bot to use dynamic content loading?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, googlebot

From the best I know, if you use AJAX or javascript links in your website, it hurts SEO as the google bot has troubles crawling your site, basically it likes anchor tags.

So it's a general saying to avoid AJAX or Flash in your website, though some saying that the google bot knows to read javascript links.

Now i believe it's possible to manipulate the google bot somehow, and when meaning manipulate i **DON'T** mean anything illegal or black hatting, I just want to Ajaxise my website.

My question is divided to 2:

- Is it possible to "present" google bot with 1 version of the site, and users with another? I've read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821256/how-to-tell-google-bot-to-skip-part-of-html) that base64 encoding your content may confuse the bot, but that seems like a bad solution to me.

Likewise, the possibilities you can add to robot.txt file is only no index and no follow, as far as i know.

- Is it possible to output the HTML as regular unajaxised website with Anchor links and after window finishes loading, then edit the anchor tags to preform dynamic content loading? i mean i know that it **is** possible, but will the google bot scan the after that event or before? on the same weight is it possible to block that parts of Javascript code from the google bot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an SEO question, not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't manipulate search engine bots to do things they don't normally do. You either work within their capabilities or not. Although search engines are getting better at handling JavaScript as a general rule dynamic content is not something they're going to be able to handle well or at all in most circumstances.

As far as getting search engines to read dynamic content created by JavaScript you have two options:

1. Build the site the right way from the beginning and use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Your site should work without JavaScript enabled. In fact, it should be built that way first. Then you can go back and add JavaScript that enhances the experience for users who have JavaScript enabled. That way your content is accessible to *everybody*.
2. [Use Google's Crawlable Ajax standard](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). This will allow Google to crawl content generated via Ajax. Keep in mind this only work for Google and leaves out other search engines and users without JavaScript enabled. [So it is a bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: Why can't it? it's all a matter if i can find out if the user currently accesing the site is the robots.txt, it's hard to believe it's not possible, i could just check and display site only after veryfing that the user uses any of the possible browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Build your site using [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

When you do significant Ajax stuff, use [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Then you have real URLs for everything and Google won't be a problem.