# Tell GoogleBot To Skip Part of a Page?

Tags: search, seo

I've read many links trying to figure out how to tell Google not to index parts of a page.  All the answers seem to be no, or do something lame like use IFrames.  In our case legal wants a lengthy disclaimer in the footer on every page.  This is causing an SEO issue.  Any brand new techniques to deal with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell google bot to skip part of HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821256/how-to-tell-google-bot-to-skip-part-of-html)

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there was some brand new technique.

Answer (score 0):

> In our case legal wants a lengthy disclaimer in the footer on every page. This is causing an SEO issue.

No it is not for Google. If it is present on every page, then it will be considered as boiler plate content rather than primary content for the relevancy and indexation of each page. Boiler plate content is ignored for rankings.

Google knows that sometimes content must be written on all pages for legal reasons. It does not penalize such websites dixit John Mueller in his hangout videos.